# Why is this int array not passed as an object vararg array?

Tags: java

I used this code. I am confused why this int array is not converted to an object vararg argument:

```
class MyClass {
    static void print(Object... obj) {
        System.out.println("Object…: " + obj[0]);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] array = new int[] {9, 1, 1};
        print(array);
        System.out.println(array instanceof Object);
    }
}
```

I expected the output:

```
Object…: 9
true
```

but it gives:

```
Object…: [I@140e19d
true
```

Comment: The issue is that `Object...` means `Object[]` and `int[]` can not be _converted_ to `Object[]` (`int` is a primitive, not an `Object`). However, the `int[]` array itself can be interpreted as `Object`. So you end up passing an object array `Object[]` with exactly one element in it, an `int[]`. So you have an array of arrays.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason for this is that an `int` array cannot be casted to an `Object` array implicitly. So you actually end up passing the `int` array as the first element of the `Object` array.

You could get the expected output *without changing your `main` method and without changing the parameters* if you do it like this:

```
static void print(Object... obj) {
    System.out.println("Object…: " + ((int[]) obj[0])[0]);
}
```

> Output:
>
> ```
> Object…: 9
> true
> ```

Answer (score 20):

You're running into an edge case where objects and primitives don't work as expected.
The problem is that the actual code ends up expecting `static void print(Object[])`, but `int[]` cannot be cast to `Object[]`. However it can be cast to `Object`, resulting in the following executed code: `print(new int[][]{array})`.

You get the behavior you expect by using an object-based array like `Integer[]` instead of `int[]`.

Answer (score 1):

As you know, when we use `varargs`, we can pass one or more arguments separating by comma. In fact it is a simplification of array and the Java compiler considers it as an array of specified type.

[Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html) told us that an array of objects or primitives is an object too:

> In the Java programming language, arrays are objects (§4.3.1), are
>   dynamically created, and may be assigned to variables of type Object
>   (§4.3.2). All methods of class Object may be invoked on an array.

So when you pass an `int[]` to the `print(Object... obj)` method, you are passing an object as the first element of `varargs`, then `System.out.println("Object…: " + obj[0]);` prints its reference address (default `toString()` method of an object).

Answer (score -1):

```
class MyClass {
    static void print(Object... obj) {
        System.out.println("Object…: " + obj[0]);
    }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            int[] array = new int[] {9, 1, 1};
        // To boxed array
        Integer[] oArray = Arrays.stream( array ).boxed().toArray( Integer[]::new );

            print(oArray);
            System.out.println(oArray instanceof Object);
        }
    }
```